# whats the time format of this weird date value

Tags: php, date, time, format, date-formatting

I'm working with an xml file in php and my concern is on the date field.
The xml outputs the date likes this ..

```
<EndTime>1427295540000</EndTime>
```

I'm having a hard time identifying the format of this time, and how to convert it  to  something like `2015-05-11 12:00:00`. Please help

Comment: It's timestamp, number of miliseconds since 1.1.1970.

Comment: You need to consult the PHP.net manual for time related functions. date, timestamp, mktime etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = 1427295540000 / 1000; //because we wants seconds but got miliseconds then divide by 1000
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $input);
```

you can divide value of end time by 1000, because we wants seconds in php and then pass it as second argument to `date` function with proper format as frist argument

Comment: Thank you, I tried both solutions, and they both work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in date function for this purpose

```
$time = date("h:i:sa"); //for time in hour mins and second format
$date = date("d-m-Y"); // for date in day month year format
```

Read more at [php.net](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.date.php&ei=QdcHVbSUDdGTuASj9oDYAw&usg=AFQjCNF4VXu6pkBazge9glSGj7ZpdJshpQ&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E)
or [w3schools](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fphp%2Fphp_date.asp&ei=QdcHVbSUDdGTuASj9oDYAw&usg=AFQjCNGEi7B6hKXjcktKaaQ_ZwLwED_evQ&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E)

for getting time in your time zone use php function `date_default_timezone_set("Your time zone");`

[See here for list of php timezones](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I tried both solutions, and they both work.